# How can we create a Twilio Video Room that doesn’t get destroyed within 5 minutes of creation if participants do not join?

Tags: twilio, video-conferencing

My use case involves creation of a peer-peer room using the Twilio Video REST API. I understand from the documentation that the room gets auto destroyed if no participant enters the room within 5mins of the room creation. This is becoming a bit difficult to manage as our use case doesn’t guarantee the participant entry time. Any workaround here?

Comment: Here is some documentation on that topic - https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/understanding-video-rooms#creating-rooms

Comment: I had gone through the API documentation you mentioned. It states that there is a first join timeout of 5 minutes which basically means that a room shall be destroyed if no participant joins within 5 minutes of room creation.

Comment: There are two options, REST API room creation and Ad-Hoc room creation. I am not aware of any way to extend the 5 minute room creation timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I would recommend creating the room at the same time that the first participant joins the room. That way you don't have to worry about it timing out.

Create the room and the access token at the same time and at the time you need it, not before.

Comment: I have done this exactly. Creating the room on demand and completing it as a scheduled job